# What did Menma say after the credits at the end of the AnoHana Movie?

Tags: anohana

After the credits ended in *AnoHana* movie, the screen remained black and Menma had a brief dialog sequence. Unfortunately, for whatever reason, that dialog sequence did not get translated and subtitled.

What did she say?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, now that the BD is out, I went back and checked. Here's how it goes down:

> 生まれ変わったら、何になろう？
> If I get reincarnated, what could I be?
>
> お花になろう。蝶々になろう。蟻ん子になろう。お芋になろう。
> I could be a flower, or a butterfly, or an ant, or a potato.
>
> 何になっても大丈夫だよ。だってね。
> No matter what I become, I'll be okay. You know why?
>
> 超平和バスターズはずーっと仲良しだから！
> Because the Super Peace Busters are friends forever!

Translation mine because I don't have access to the subs that were shown in theaters (I don't know if they were even released anywhere).

---

[Album of after credits scene.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBF6C.jpg)